Unable to load Maven's central repo list in Eclipse
I downloaded Eclipse 2024-06 with built-in m2e integration (for Java developers).  However, I am not able to view the central repo's list at all via Eclipse's 'Maven Repository' view.  In fact, under 'global repos' node there are no URL entries at all and the local repository path is greyed out.   Firewall is not blocking.
Anyone had to deal with this problem?   if so, how do I resolve this bug?
=====UPDATE=====
Below are the screenshots of Neon.3 and Eclipse 2024.
Per Neon.3 I would expect to see the list of libraries
However, in Eclipse 2024, the 'central' node does not expand..Why? and whats the solution?



Seems like a networking issue. Have you tested network connectivity to Maven central? Why do you think it is a bug?

@aled, the reason I know it's not network is because I have an older version of Eclipse running m2e without any problems...

Same proxy configuration in the old version?

@aled same config (ie all default settings).  I keep on seeing this line, but not sure what is triggering it:   [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryRefreshJob -- Queued refresh request: []

What do you mean by "the central repo's list"? Does your Maven Repositories view show the nodes Local Repositories and Global Repositories with the sub-node central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)? If not, please tell whether you have a .m2/settings.xml file and, if so, what is in it, as well as what you have in the preferences Maven > User Settings. Be aware that nowadays no Maven indexes are downloaded as in the past. Searching for artifacts can be done directly in the Maven POM editor in the pom.xml tab via the content assist.

@howlger, yes central repo is central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and that repo's response is supposed to be a node-tree list returned to the client.
also, the Maven POM editor does not produce any results via the content assist

Again, what do you mean by "the central repo's list" and for what purpose do you need it? Please show a screenshot of your Maven Repositories view with the Global Repositories node expanded.

@howlger, the Global Repositories node does NOT expand.   that is exactly my question... :)   instead of expected list at that node, there is just nothing...

In my case, Global Repositories has only the child node central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) which can not expanded further. In the past, it could be expanded further. But the behavior has changed. According to your question, you do not seem to be aware of this change ("[...] and the local repository path is greyed out"). Please show a screenshot of the Maven Repositories view, name all the items that you expect, but that are actually missing and tell for which purpose you need them.

@howlger, thanks!   yes I am not aware of the changes.   Last time I used Maven was back in the days of Eclipse neon.3 era (ie 8 or so years ago).    In light of this change, how can I graphically choose and browse dependencies?   I will upload a screenshot my original message in just a few minutes...  Thanks again!

In the past, the index from Maven central was downloaded which was slow. Nowadays the search is used. In the Maven POM editor in the dependencies section or in the plugins section you just need to type to get the list to choose from via content assist.

@howlger, thanks!   I tried content assist too... that does not work either..   it does work great on neon.3 though...

What you are saying is not reasonable for me. Nowadays it is faster than it was seven years ago, and the information is provided where it is needed. Your question is still an XY problem, asking about X without any information about your use case Y. I've already told you why, but I can't give you a solution to a problem you haven't told about.
